# How to disable auto reformat when performing structural replacing in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, I wrote some codes like blow

```
val text: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textviewExample) // 1
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonExample) // 2
```

Basically both ways are possible, but I just wanted to be consistent with my coding style, so I want to call `findViewById` method like how `button` line is written. This project has been old, so some of lines have style of `text` variable (1), while others have `button` variable's (2)

To save the time, I could use `Structural Replace` feature. This feature has been really helpful to me, so I tried to use it for this case too. I wrote template like below

```
val $varaible$: $type$ = findViewById($id$)
```

->

```
val $varaible$ = findViewById<$type$>($id$)
```

It could detect lines properly, but replacing has problem. I will give an example with above `text` variable's line. So if we replace this line, it should be written below

```
val text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textviewExample)
```

But what Android Studio does is like below

```
val text: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textviewExample)
```

I want `: TextView` part to be gone, but Android Studio keeps reformatting it to have explicit type specification. This isn't problem of template because if I make it show preview of how this line will be changed to, it shows desired result. But it doesn't when I actually click replace button. Below is actual example

[image]

Preview shows like below

[image]

But then result becomes below

[image]

And finally, below is template that I wrote

[image]

I even tried to add regex to `$variable$` section as `[^:]+` for the case when `$variable$` itself included whole part of `text: TextView`, but it didn't work. I assume AS tries to replace line as `val text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textviewExample)`, then something catches explicit type specification got deleted, and reformat into `val text: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textviewExample)` back

So I wonder if there's a way to disable such auto-reformatting, or replace codes as raw text